# RIP Stephen Furst, actor for Vir Cotto

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

On June 17, 2017, Stephen Furst [passed away](http://hosted.ap.org/dynamic/stories/U/US_OBIT_STEPHEN_FURST?SITE=AP&SECTION=HOME&TEMPLATE=DEFAULT) at the age of 63 after complications with diabetes.

While most obituaries highlighted his role as Flounder in the movie *Animal House*, science fiction fans are more likely to remember him for being on *Babylon 5* playing the role of Vir Cotto, diplomatic attaché and later emperor of the Centauri. He was also the voice of Booster and other characters in the TV show *Buzz Lightyear of Star Command*.

Let's not forget too that Stephen Furst had many additional years of life, thanks to the generosity of a fan who [anonymously donated their kidney to him](http://leewochner.com/blog/?p=493).

> Vir Cotto: A hell of a life.
>   Lennier: [smiles] …you win.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: waving 1]

[image: waving 2]

**RIP Mr Furst.** Unlike Mr Morden, you will be missed.

Comment: Great minds think alike

Answer (score 7):

A great acting talent and the perfect actor for the role of Vir. RIP.

Comment: Ah, but in my answer you can actually see the movement :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Mine has sound.